# How to abort a widget build in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Context: I am using Flutter web and it is very difficult to get all the data a certain page route needs so I want to redirect the user to the welcome screen when he presses refresh which is not something I would like the user to do. The following code doesn't work. Essentially I want to abort the build and just return.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (first) {
      first = false;
      final arguments = (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments ??
          <String, dynamic>{}) as Map;

      if (!arguments.containsKey('id')) {
        //something weird is going on maybe the user refreshed
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, WelcomeScreen.routeName);
        return Container();
      }
    }
}
```

It produces the error:

> setstate or markneedsbuild called during build

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this in the first build, and not in for example initState?

Comment: do I have the settings.arguments object in initstate?

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    if (kIsWeb) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        if (_refreshed) {
          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen()),
              (route) => false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```